# Synchronous view flipping

Tags: android, animation, synchronous, viewflipper

I'm using a ViewFlipper to flip between three Views with a simple animation. This animation persists for about 1 minute before complete and this is the point.
The code immediately below the showNext() called to start flipping the views is reached BEFORE the animation end producing an ugly effect.

Is it possible to call a synchronous showNext() that doesn't returns until animation completes?
Otherwise, is it possible to register a Listner for an ipotetic *OnAnimationComplete* event?

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an animation end listener-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29